# Hum/noise from audio interface after some time of inactivity - is there a setting for it?

Tags: windows, audio, sleep, power-management, powersave

I have a laptop and external amplifier + speakers connected to its internal audio interface / analog output jack, which usually works fine.

But for some time (months or year even), whenever no audio is playing for a number of minutes, the external speakers start to produce a hum and other noise on top of it.
(I suspect there was an update that changed defaults at some point... I don't recall this always being like this)

So no, this is **not** about a ground loop, the effect is *not permanent*.
As soon as I play some audio again briefly and stop it, this noise will be gone for some more time, until it starts again later.
Since all the superfluous clicky sounds in my Windows are turned off, there will be no audio signal sent from any application once I don't play any media.

I observed that I also get that hum when I set the computer into sleep/powersave mode.
So my suspicion is that this might be some sort of power saving feature - when there is no audio being sent to the device for a certain time, the audio interface (with perhaps an integrated linear headphone amp that would suck a little power otherwise) is powered down, the output goes high impedance and I'm picking up noise?

If that's correct - is there some setting somewhere to disable that? I looked in the power management settings and found nothing about audio devices.

Comment: There could be an application that automatically adjusts audio gain (e.g., a compressor or automatic volume control, AVC, or audio gain control, AGC), so that when there is no signal, it "cranks up" the volume. This is built into Windows *microphone input*, but I've not seen it for audio output. Check the Sound CPL.

Comment: Try with linux or mac or another line level device to see if the problem follows. (It could be in your external amp?) Update your audio drivers to manufacturers', (not ms generics) It could just be your laptop has a high noise floor. OR the chip goes quiet and your line becomes an antenna.  Is there no digital interconnect from your PC to amp? Might pay to chuck a USB DAC in there if you're really serious about it.

Comment: Seriously, before I buy extra hardware because of that stupid bug / bad setting, I'll write a little program that sends a zero sample once every minute or so to the default audio device... Given the evidence, that _would_ work, but it's kinda stupid.